# How can you productively find all recordings of a piece?

Tags: cd

I'm unsettled to find merely 2 CD's of Rautavaara's Piano Concertos 1 and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No._2_(Rautavaara))

> - [Laura Mikkola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Mikkola) (pianist), [Netherlands Radio Symphony Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Radio_Symphony_Orchestra), [Eri Klas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eri_Klas) (conductor), [Naxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxos_Records) (record company)
> - [Ralf Gothoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralf_Gothoni) (pianist), [Leipzig Radio Symphony Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leipzig_Radio_Symphony_Orchestra), [Max Pommer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Pommer) (conductor), [Ondine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ondine_(record_label)) (record company)

and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No._3_(Rautavaara))

> - [Vladimir Ashkenazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Ashkenazy) (pianist/conductor), [Helsinki Philharmonic Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Philharmonic_Orchestra), [Ondine, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ondine_(record_label)) (record company)
> - [Laura Mikkola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_Mikkola) (pianist), [Netherlands Radio Symphony Orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Radio_Symphony_Orchestra), [Eri Klas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eri_Klas) (conductor), [Naxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxos_Records) (record company).

Rautavaara isn't even listed on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:People_with_recordings#fcfrom:R)! Have I overlooked any other catalog or database?

Comment: Did you look in Discogs and Musicbrainz?

Comment: @nelgin No. Never heard of them before. thanks for introduction.